# how to know if Activity resumed by shortcut or by another top activity

Tags: android

The main activity creates a shortcut to homescreen, all goes good but it needs to know an extra value when it starts by shortcut. So I used this while creating shortcut

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, "Some string info here");
```

And `onResume` retrieve value like this

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_ID))
    ShowToast(getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_ID));
```

Everything works fine, lets take some examples

1. Activity never launched, Home screen shortcut pressed and A toast appears, Nice.
2. Activity is in background, Home screen shortcut pressed and A toast appears, Nice.
3. Activity is in use, another activity is launched, when back, toast appears, Not nice.
4. Activity is in background with no extra, Shortcut pressed, Nothing appears.

In 3rd example, it does what it suppose to do. But how do I know if activity is resumed/launched by shortcut ?

Comment: Use the extra only once. Remove the extra after first onResume.

Comment: Yes exactly but now I have another problem. Added 4th case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set an extra in launcher Intent, and want to get the extra when this activity is opened in any state.

The problem you meet:

> Activity is in background with no extra, Shortcut pressed, Nothing
>   appears.

This is because that your activity is started already, the launcher intent just use the existing task as the front task, and its extra data is lost in such situation.

To solve this, you need 2 steps:

1. Add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to this activity in your manifest.
2. Put the extra data handling codes in both `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`, not in `onResume()`.

Comment: Works perfect, but no need to change launchMode. Just use `onNewIntenet` and call setIntent() with new intent.

Answer (score 1):

How are you removing the extra `EXTRA_ID`? You should do it like:

In `onResume()`:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_ID)) {
    ShowToast(getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_ID));
    getIntent().removeExtra(EXTRA_ID);
}
```

Comment: Removing did solve the 3rd case, but it creates another. If app goes in background and shortcut presses, nothing appears.

Comment: @xmenW.K. You will need to override the `onNewIntent()` method(as faylon has mentioned in his answer below) and place the if-block in it.